# Как убрать ширину блока в блоке с overflow: hidden?

Tags: css3, прокрутка, css

Вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/G6DFL/ .

Если фрейм result уменьшить до ширины меньше чем 200px то появляется скролл, Также это происходит если окно браузера уменьшить до 200px.

Как не трогая все что внутри own, сделать так что бы все блоки которые не влазят в own не было видно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это то, что вам нужно?
http://jsfiddle.net/YNr3b/

По всей видимости скролл появляется из-за того, что у одного из дочерних элементов position:absolute, и overflow:hidden у родительского элемента на него не действует. Тут помогает добавление position:relative у родительского элемента.